# react js : input toggle swich not toggling on onChnage

Tags: reactjs

i have a toggle swicth

```
 <label class="switch">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id="checked"
          checked={domestic_voilence}
          onChange={handleChangeTogle}
        />

        <span class="slider"></span>
      </label>
```

from api i am getting value wether my toggle swich is true or false

```
 useEffect(() => {
  axios
      .get(
        `analytics/get-personal-details/?customer=` +
          22,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json",
            Authorization: `token  6fa443340e173e8013ee91ccdd518d3dc9113046`
          }
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);

        setdomestic(res.data[0].domestic);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

using on change i am trying to change the value of toggle swich

```
 const handleChangeTogle = (e) => {
  
    setdomestic(!domestic);
   
  };
```

when submit button is clicked i want to submit data to api

```
const SubmitData = () => {
    console.log(domestic);
  };
```

working code i have made codesandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you are updating wrong SetState value.. try instead

working code..  https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-chihiro-tszpp4?file=/src/App.js:838-943

```
const handleChangeTogle = (e) => {
    setdomestic_voilence(!domestic_voilence);
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the wrong value, it should be

```
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id="checked"
            checked={domestic}
            onChange={handleChangeTogle}
          />
```

instead of the original

```
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id="checked"
            checked={domestic_voilence}
            onChange={handleChangeTogle}
          />
```

Also when on component mount, set your checkbox value from the result

```
setdomestic(res.data[0].domestic_voilence);
```

[image: Edit strange-edison-onopz9]